# How to make a global property that is visible within all pages in a Windows 10 app?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-10, uwp, windows-10-universal

i am thinking of an app that represents a Store, i am using a GridView to view the items and the data is represented as an ObservableCollection.

my XAML Code :

```
xmlns:data="using:ItemsStore.Models"

<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind ItemsList}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Item">                 
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                       <Image Source="{x:Bind ImageSource}"/>
                       <TextBlock  Text="{x:Bind Name}"/>
                       <TextBlock  Text="{x:Bind Disc}"/>

                    </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

the C# Code in the MainPage :

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsList;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<Item>(); 
    }
}
```

I added a button and some input controls to add new items to the ItemsList and it works just fine, but i want to make another page that contains the controls and the logic to add new Items to the List, so i made the AddNew.xaml page but i couldn't access the ObservableCollection in the MainPage to add new items to it, and i also tried to make the ObservableCollection a static field and i managed to access the Collection in the MainPage but i saw no change in the MainPage after updating the Collection in the AddNew Page.

I think that the problem is because of the initializing statement in the MainPage Constructor , every time i navigate to the AddNew page and update the Collection and then navigate back to the MainPage the Constrctor gets Called and the Collection is reset, so the solution is about making the ObservableCollection a golbal variable and initializing it Somewhere out of the MainPage constructor , OR simply initialze the Collection within an event handler that excutes only once when the app launces.

so my questions are :
1- is there any way to make a global ObservableCollection that is visible to every page in the app ? if so, How can i refrence it in the binding statement (x:Bind theGlobalCollection) or

2- is there any event that is get trigged only once through the app life time ?

i am very sorry for this big question, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correct, you could simply remove the instatiation from the constructor and change the field to this:

`public static ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsList = new ObservableCollection<Item>();`

In this way, the **ItemsList** is only instantiated once.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [site](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6ad460a8-e867-464e-b5e5-97749a1fcf4d/global-shared-observablecollection?forum=wpf), If you are wanting an `ObservableCollection`  for all the views that you can databind in xaml, you can use `Application.Current.Resources`. For more information, see the [reference](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29859.wpf-tips-bind-to-current-item-of-collection.aspx).

Example (from source):

```
public class PeopleViewModel : NotifyUIBase
{
    public ListCollectionView PeopleCollectionView {get; set;}
    private Person CurrentPerson
    {
        get { return PeopleCollectionView.CurrentItem as Person; }
        set
        {
            PeopleCollectionView.MoveCurrentTo(value);
            RaisePropertyChanged();

        }
    }
    public PeopleViewModel()
    {
        PeopleCollectionView = Application.Current.Resources["PeopleCollectionView"] as ListCollectionView;
        PeopleCollectionView.MoveCurrentToPosition(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: this seems to work but actually the answer of Xerillio got the job done, thank you for your time i really appreciate it.